# Do elementary column operations change the null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, homogeneous-equation

I know elementary row operations do not change the null space or the row space but they do change the column space. Likewise, elementary column operations change the row space but not the column space. Do they chance the null space? Why/why not?

I think they will not change the null space of the transpose of A, right? But I don't know what they will do to A itself.

Comment: Yes, they do. For instance, $\ker\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}\ne\ker\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}\ne\ker\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: Column operations do not change the column space, and therefore neither do they change its "annihilator", by which I mean $\{x\in\Bbb R^n\,:\, \forall v\in \operatorname{col}A, v^\top x=0\}$. The latter is, incidentally, $\ker (A^\top)$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio No, the kernel is the orthogonal complement of the _row_ space. It was you who posted the simple example showing the kernel _does_ change - that makes this comment curious...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The OP also asks for the kernel of $A^\top$, which is the orthogonal complement of the row space of $A^\top$, which is the transponse of the column space of $A$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the ${}^\perp$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio thank you!!